# extrude some faces along a vector combination of two normal axes and one global axis

Tags: modeling, faces, extrude

[image]Hi everybody, I’m Davide and i’m a newbie. i'm using 3.6 ver; i have to extrude some faces so that the extrusion vector is a combination of face normal (along x,y) and global orientation (along z). I succed in doing this but in a very tricky way, and i’m wondering if there is a fast way to do this or if exists an addon. I’ve been searching online for a few days without finding a solution any suggestion would be of great help. in the attached img there's what i'm trying to achieve, thanks

Comment: Just to make sure this is understood correctly: you want to move the vertex along the vector which is the projection of global Z onto the triangle?

Comment: what i'm try to do is a sort of "one click" to achieve the following behaviour: extrude face along its z normal, move on z global axis the extruded face to allign to the orginal one and the two faces must have a distance of 1.2

Comment: Isn't that just (With 'Global' Transform Orientation set.. )  `EZZ 1.2` ? I'm sure it's not.. I must be missing something..

Comment: thanks Robin for your replies. doing EZZ 1.2 in 'Global' transform orientation extrudes the face along z 'Normal' but the extruded face is not at same z 'Global' height of the original one(unless it's not perpendicular to xy 'Global' plane) and i have to raise or lower it to make it so. After doing this, however, the two faces are no longer at the right distance and I have to fix them. I'm searching a workaround to use a command like extrude (or extrude with an option) to do this in a "oneclik" way.

Comment: but I'm afraid I'll have to bang my head with scripting.

Comment: OK, I'll go back to the definition in the first comment

Comment: HI Robin thanks for your time and sorry for my delay in replying but i was fighting against a big wasp nest. At first i didn't unserstand your first comment but now i think it's as you say. thank

Comment: Hi Robin thanks, i've found a workarond, maybe a little tricky but it works for me. with geometry nodes i’ve extruded faces of 0 scale and then i’ve moved them on z normal = 0 and x,y calculated finding Hipo of x y normals, divided with that the distance i’ve choosen in input attributes and multiply the result for respective x and y normals to find the offset on these axis and here it is.

cheers

Davide

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNg2r.jpg

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vfWf.jpg